# Do I need Vagrant to use a Docker Linux image if I'm on a Windows host?

Tags: docker, vagrant, containers, virtual-machine

I use Vagrant to run a CentOS VM so that my dev machine is identical to production.

I want to "switch" to Docker as it appears to do the same job and it's more lightweight.

However, my impression is that Docker makes a container using the host's resources (in my case, Windows). Meaning if I run Docker on my Windows machine, it will use Windows' resources. Therefore, it's not going to be identical to production (which uses "pure" CentOS).

That said, for dev and prod to be truly identical, I need to use a Linux VM (via Vagrant) then install Docker from there, is this correct?

Comment: The whole point of containers is that it doesn't matter what the host is, other than can it run Windows or Linux containers. If you build a Linux container, then it will behave the same everywhere that Linux containers can run. If you build a Windows container, then it will behave the same everywhere that Windows containers can run. It seems like you should spend some more time researching Docker, perhaps watch some of the great talks given on YouTube. It sounds like it will accomplish what you want, but you should still understand more of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Docker for windows uses a virtual machine (HyperV) when you use it. It's a linux distro.
For this to work, you need to have windows pro though, as home does not come with HyperV.

If you use a windows home installation, you could instead use 'Docker Toolbox', which uses virtual box instead of HyperV. It works okay, but I think there are some limitations and performance differences between the two solutions.

Comment: I can Vagrant so I guess I can run Docker? Anyway do you mean to say my assumption is wrong and that even if I'm on Windows, I will still get a full CentOS experience that is identical to production (if production also uses the same Docker image)?

Comment: If you have no experience of docker, I recommend reading up on it a bit before swapping from vagrant. But yes, even if you run on windows, the built container will work just as if it was built and running on a CentOS machine.

Comment: If you expect "a full CentOS experience" then I would stick with your Vagrant/VM solution; the process of setting up Docker containers can be substantially different.  That's doubly true if you're not actually changing your production environment to be Docker-based.

Comment: I did read quite a bit and [this image](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ling-Hong_Hung/publication/299771559/figure/fig4/AS:359778707623937@1462789336136/A-comparison-of-the-architecture-of-virtual-machines-and-Docker-software.png) kinda summarized my assumption. The 3rd column gave me an impression that I need to install a VM first but what you're saying is that Docker does this automatically if the host is on Windows?

Comment: @DavidMaze I plan to make the production also Docker-based.

Comment: If you use windows pro, hyper-v is probably already installed (possibly not activated though). If you run on windows home, I'm fairly certain that Docker Toolbox installs vbox for you, but else the installation instructions should tell you what to do.